# Legacy Nvidia graphics driver support

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

So. I've made the switch to Linux. I've been using ubunto studio distro and think it's great. But I have an issue with one of my graphics cards. I run two legacy Nvidia cards a GTX 650 witch needs package 470 and a 8500 gs Wich needs package 390 I can't seen to find a way to get this setup at all. After hours of research. I can get the 470 package no problem. But the 390 is not in any repository. I've tried downloading the installers from Nvidia and manually installing them again the 470 no problem but the 390 fails because of an identification error and crashes my system. I would post info but right now I'm left with only my phone to get on line. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Btw I run on a legacy bios if that's important

Comment: Ubuntu stodio 20.1 64 bit. Tried the same processes on pop os with same result.

Comment: Any actual version number is also quite helpful.